# Divergence-free vector field on a 2-sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

What is the solution of the differential equation

$$\text{div}X=0$$

on the 2-sphere?

Comment: Your title does not quite correspond to the actual question.

Comment: There is an infinite-dimensional family of solutions to this on any Riemannian manifold.

Comment: If someone already answered your post, do not change it dramatically like you just did. Please, post another question instead. If you want to save up time, you can copy and paste what you wrote from the edit history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\def\div{\operatorname{div}}$Let $\nu$ be the volume form on the sphere. The map $X\mapsto\nu(X,\mathord-)$ gives a bijection from vector fields to $1$-forms and, in particular, if $h:S^2\to\mathbb R$ is a smooth function, there is a unique vector field $X_h$ such that $\nu(X_h,Y)=dh(Y)$ for all vector fields $Y$. Using [Cartan's magic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#The_Lie_derivative_of_a_differential_form) it is easy to see that $\def\L{\mathcal L}\L_{X_h}\nu$, the Lie derivative of $\nu$ in the direction of $X_h$, vanishes. Since $\L_{X_h}\nu=\div(X_h)\nu$ and $\nu$ vanishes nowhere, we see that $\div(X_h)=0$.

In this way, we find a divergence-free vector on the sphere for each function $h$. In fact, they all arise in this way. This is a more complicated result —it depends on the simply-connectedness of the sphere and is a symplectic thing. Let's see: let $X$ be a vector field on the sphere with zero divergence, so that $\L_X\nu=0$. Using Cartan's formula, we see that the $1$-form $i_X\nu$ which we get by contracting $\nu$ with $X$ is closed. It therefore has a class in the degree $1$ de Rham cohomology vector space $[i_X\nu]\in H^1(S^2)$. As this vector space is zero, because the sphere is simply connected, $i_X\nu$ has to be exact, that is, there exists a function $h:S^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $i_X\nu=dh$. If you consider what this means, you see that $X$ is in fact equal to the vector field $X_h$.

Comment: With the standard metric, $X_h$ is a $90^\circ$ rotation of $\nabla h$. It's tangent to the level curves of $h$.